# Chrome extension popup not opening

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension, popup

I understand that popups are made up of a html file. Below is my code. For some reason the popup window won't open when I click the icon. Any ideas on what the problem may be?

```
{
    "name": "Popup Snake",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "A simple snake game popup, that can be opened by clicking the icon in the top right (after installing)",
    "page_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing page_action to browser_action
So like this:

```
{
"name": "Popup Snake",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "A simple snake game popup, that can be opened by clicking the icon in the top right (after installing)",
"browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"manifest_version": 2
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem as well. But instead of changing it to **browser_action**, i instead kept the **page_action**. see [declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent)

The thing I've heard is, browser_action should only be used if your extension use features that make sense on most pages. Else use page action.

Source: [What are the differences between page action and browser action?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44713058/5277059)

So with page_action, you specify what website your extension would work on with said declarativeContent.